# how is it possible to show form data and uploaded image to a page in flask

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

how is it possible to show form data and uploaded image to a page. like it's a student application website , where student will fill his information along with his photo. so when he submits, he will be redirected to another page "apply.html" with his own information filled and a image on the page, kind of admit card.

i am able to upload image to my "static/uploads" folder and also when form is submited user is redirected to "apply.html" with information filled on it but i don't find a way to show image on "apply.html"

here is my code

```
@app.route('/form.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
  nform = NewRegistration(request.form)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if nform.validate() == False:
      flash('All fields are required.')
      return render_template('form.html', form=nform)
    else:

        try:
            file = request.files['file']
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        except Exception as e:
            print "Form without file "+e
        post = request.form['element_15'].strip()
        name = request.form['element_1_1'].strip()
        last = request.form['element_1_2'].strip()
        Name = str(name)+ ' ' +str(last)
        father = request.form['element_2'].strip()
        mother = request.form['element_3'].strip()
        gender = request.form['element_17'].strip()
        data = {'Name' : Name, 'post' : post, 'father' : father}
        return render_template("apply.html", data=data)

    elif request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template('form.html', form=nform)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `apply.html` template, you can have an `<img>` tag pointing to the image you uploaded. Consider saving the image in the `static` folder under an img folder. Then you can just use:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/' + filename)}}">
```

in order to use filename add a filename variable to your form view return statement:

```
return render_template("apply.html", data=data, filename=filename)
```

Comment: i have the image tag in apply.html, but m not getting the logic to put on routes.py.

Comment: it's working a bit, it's showing the correct name of the image, but failed to load corretly.

Comment: ok done, sorry ,  mind was so tired, even i coudn't think a simple logic. did. thankyou

Comment: is `UPLOAD_FOLDER` in your config set up to be `/static/img`??

Comment: i just had to do this <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename)}}">. i am done, it worked . Thanks for your time. thank you so much